# Using google play scraper to get app info but want to make it work for a list of id's

Tags: python, node.js

However, the scraper is made to get app info after entering the id and everytime, we need to change the id; if we want to get another app info. Here, I have file appid.txt in which 100s of app id are there and i want to make it work the script for this file so that i don't need to change the id everytime.

`````
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.app({appId: 'appid.txt'})
  .then(console.log, console.log);
````

Sorry! For my bad english.
`````